# Inflate a new layout into a ViewStub

Tags: android

I have a [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) which I want to change the inflated view it contains at run-time multiple of times.

Is it possible to do that? or should I simply use a `ViewGroup` instead and inflate a different view every time?

Comment: You can only change the inflated layout before you call inflate() i think, once you callit the ViewStub is removed from the viewGroup i think. please explain better what you want to do so that we can discuss the best solution.

Comment: Inflate one view, and then inflate another one, same way as replacing fragments.

Comment: ok then using a RelativeLayout/FrameLayout with multiple ViewStub could be a solution. But if after replace you want to remove the past view from the layout then you could simply keep a LayoutParams object and use it with every View ( inflated manually ) you want to put in the layout. So on switch you do inflate/Remove oldView /Add the new view with the oldView params